# Javascript replace a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace, hyperlink

I want to change this

```
[s=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Javascript%20replace%20a%20string]Text[/s]
```

into this

```
 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Javascript%20replace%20a%20string">Text</a>
```

using javascript

I have try this one.

```
<script>
var str = "[s=/site_menu.xhtml?get-d=4%2027&get-id=315&get-title=DanMachi%20Season%202&get-main=DanMachi]DanMachi Season 2[/s]";
var res = str.replace("[s=", '&lt;a href="');
var ser = res.replace("[/s]", "&lt;/a&gt;");
var serr = ser.replace("]", ':admin-hash-amp:"&gt;');
document.write(serr);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider simply creating a function that would encapsulate all of this for you, especially if you plan on using in within multiple areas of your application:

```
function toHyperLink(input){
    return input.replace('[s=','<a href="')
                .replace(']','">')
                .replace('[/s]','</a>');
}
```

**Example**

```js
var input = '[s=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Javascript%20replace%20a%20string]Text[/s]';
console.log(`Input: ${input}`);
console.log(`Output: ${convertToHyperlink(input)}`);

function convertToHyperlink(input) {
  return input.replace('[s=', '<a href="').replace(']', '">').replace('[/s]', '</a>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you do your convert you should create an element instead of write that out.

```
var str = "[s=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Javascript%20replace%20a%20string]Text[/s]";
var res = str.replace("[s=", '&lt;a href="');
var ser = res.replace("[/s]", "&lt;/a&gt;");
var serr = ser.replace("]", '"&gt;');    

var text = serr.slice(serr.indexOf("&gt;") + 4, serr.indexOf("&lt;/a&gt"))
var href = serr.slice(serr.indexOf("href=\"") + 6, serr.indexOf("\"&gt"))

var link = document.createElement("a");
link.text = text;
link.href = href;

document.getElementById("myDIV").appendChild(link);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var str = "[s=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Javascript%20replace%20a%20string]Text[/s]";
var r = str.replace(/\[s=(.*?)\](.*?)(\[\/s\])/gi,"<a href='$1'>$2</a>");
document.write(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may also do like;

```js
var str = "[s=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Javascript%20replace%20a%20string]Text[/s]",
    res = str.replace(/\[s(.+)\](.+)\[\/s\]/, "<a href$1>$2</a>");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: i want to <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">text</a>      change this little bit                                                                                              <a href="http://stackoverflow.com(want to put some text here)">text</a>     

pls help